# Error Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.text.Editable android.widget.EditText.getText()' on a null object reference

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I have been trying to create a module in the app. This module is like create a new user profile. When user taps on the icon in the toolbar it shows the dialog box which has the form.

The form has 5 main input

1. Name --> Used EditText
2. Gender --> Used RadioGroup
3. Height --> Used EditText
4. Weight --> Used EditText
5. Age --> Used EditText

When I click on the dialog box **done** button it should save the information in the SQLite database and create a **usercard** in the phone at the sametime. User can create N number of profile in the app and for that user has to fill the info and tap on the done but whenever user taps on the done button it crashes the whole app. This much I have gone so far and encountered a problem -

**add_form.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/form_title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#3498DB"
        android:textColor="#FFF"
        android:textSize="21sp"
        android:padding="16dp"
        android:text="ADD PERSON"/>
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="16dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/form_title">
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/person_name"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingTop="16dp"
            android:paddingBottom="16dp"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:hint="PERSON NAME"
            android:inputType="text" />

        <RadioGroup
            android:id="@+id/gender_selection"
            android:layout_below="@+id/person_name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/male"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="MALE"
                android:onClick="RadioButtonClicked"
                />
            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/female"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="FEMALE"
                android:onClick="RadioButtonClicked"/>
        </RadioGroup>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/person_metrics"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/gender_selection">
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_weight="1">
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:text="WEIGHT"/>
                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/person_weight"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:padding="16dp"
                    android:textSize="21sp"
                    android:hint="KG"
                    android:inputType="text" />
            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_weight="1">
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:text="HEIGHT"/>
                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/person_height"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:padding="16dp"
                    android:textSize="21sp"
                    android:hint="M"
                    android:inputType="text" />
            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_weight="1">
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:text="AGE"/>
                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/person_age"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:padding="16dp"
                    android:textSize="21sp"
                    android:hint="Y"
                    android:inputType="text" />
            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**PersonDBHelper.java**

```
package com.example.kuro.bloodpressure;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.DatabaseErrorHandler;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.text.Editable;

/**
 * Created by Kuro on 4/18/2016.
 */
public class PersonDBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "person_profile.db";
    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "person_info_table";
    public static final String id = "ID";
    public static final String name = "NAME";
    public static final String gender = "GENDER";
    public static final String weight = "WEIGHT";
    public static final String height = "HEIGHT";
    public static final String age = "AGE";
//    public static final String blood_pressure_upper = "BPU";
//    public static final String blood_pressure_lowser = "BPL";
//    public static final String heart_beat = "HB";

    public PersonDBHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME,null,1);
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL("create table " + TABLE_NAME +
                "(ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
                " NAME STRING, " +
                " GENDER STRING," +
                " WEIGHT INTEGER," +
                " HEIGHT INTEGER, " +
                " AGE INTEGER)");
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXSITS"+TABLE_NAME);
        onCreate(db);
    }

    public boolean insertData(String name, String gender, String weight, String height, String age){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();

        contentValues.put(name,name);
        contentValues.put(gender,gender);
        contentValues.put(weight,weight);
        contentValues.put(height,height);
        contentValues.put(age, age);

        long result = db.insert(TABLE_NAME,null,contentValues);
        if (result==-1) return false;
        else return true;
    }

    public Cursor getAllData(){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor res = db.rawQuery("select * from"+TABLE_NAME,null);
        return res;
    }
}
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.example.kuro.bloodpressure;

import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import org.w3c.dom.Text;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public Toolbar mtoolbar;
    public TabLayout mtabLayout;
    public ViewPager mviewPager;
    public ViewPagerAdapter viewPagerAdapter;
    PersonDBHelper mydb;

    EditText name, weight, height, age;
    RadioGroup mradioGroup;
    RadioButton male,female;
    TextView selectedGender;
    private String gender_value;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mtoolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(mtoolbar);

        mtabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tablayout);
        mviewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        viewPagerAdapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        viewPagerAdapter.addFragments(new Measure(), "MEASURE");
        viewPagerAdapter.addFragments(new People(), "PEOPLE");
        mviewPager.setAdapter(viewPagerAdapter);
        mtabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mviewPager);

        mydb = new PersonDBHelper(this);


    }

    public void RadioButtonClicked(View view) {
        boolean checked = ((RadioButton) view).isChecked();
        switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.male:
                if (checked)gender_value = "male";
                else male.setChecked(false);
                break;
            case R.id.female:
                if (checked) gender_value = "female";
                else female.setChecked(false);
                break;
        }

    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public void viewAll(){

    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.add_person:
                AlertDialog.Builder add_people_form = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
                add_people_form.setView(R.layout.add_form)
                        .setCancelable(false)
                        .setPositiveButton("DONE", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {


                                name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.person_name);
                                mradioGroup = (RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.gender_selection);
                                male = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.male);
                                female = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.female);
                                weight = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.person_weight);
                                height = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.person_height);
                                age = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.person_age);


                                String user_name = (String) name.getText().toString();
                                String user_gender = (String) gender_value;
                                String user_weight = (String) weight.getText().toString();
                                String user_height = (String) height.getText().toString();
                                String user_age = (String) age.getText().toString();

                                boolean isInserted = mydb.insertData(user_name,user_gender,user_weight,user_height,user_age);
                                if(isInserted==true)
                                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"ADDED",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                else
                                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"NOT ADDED",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }
                        })
                        .setNegativeButton("CANCLE", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                dialog.cancel();
                            }
                        });
                AlertDialog alert = add_people_form.create();
                alert.show();
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

}
```

**Logcat**

```
04-18 23:22:44.207 28079-28079/com.example.kuro.bloodpressure E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                            Process: com.example.kuro.bloodpressure, PID: 28079
                                                                            java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.text.Editable android.widget.EditText.getText()' on a null object reference
                                                                                at com.example.kuro.bloodpressure.MainActivity$2.onClick(MainActivity.java:111)
                                                                                at com.android.internal.app.AlertController$ButtonHandler.handleMessage(AlertController.java:162)
                                                                                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5343)
                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:905)
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:700)
```

Comment: Look carefully at the difference in the code in that post and what you have. You need to inflate the layout first, then call findViewById on the dialog's vie instead of the activity.

Comment: @cricket_007 Sorry I am new to android and this in my first app so can you please elaborate more on your suggestion what is inflate and how to I use it?

Comment: Have you read the code in the post I linked to? The line of code that says `factory.inflate` in particular is what you are missing. The process of "inflating" in Android refers to taking an XML file and converting it into a Java object.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're mixing together dialog and activity views. `findViewById` is a method of `Activity` but the view you're trying to use is not part of the activity.

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.add_person: {
            createAddPersonDialog().show();
        }
        default: {
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
}

private Dialog createAddPersonDialog() {
    final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);

    // Inflate using dialog themed context.
    final Context context = builder.getContext();
    final LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.add_form, null, false);

    // Find widgets inside "view".
    final EditText name = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.person_name);
    final RadioGroup mradioGroup = (RadioGroup) view.findViewById(R.id.gender_selection);
    final RadioButton male = (RadioButton) view.findViewById(R.id.male);
    final RadioButton female = (RadioButton) view.findViewById(R.id.female);
    final EditText weight = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.person_weight);
    final EditText height = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.person_height);
    final EditText age = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.person_age);

    final View.OnClickListener listener = new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            if (which == DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE) {
                dialog.cancel();
                return;
            }

            String user_name = (String) name.getText().toString();
            String user_gender = (String) gender_value;
            String user_weight = (String) weight.getText().toString();
            String user_height = (String) height.getText().toString();
            String user_age = (String) age.getText().toString();

            boolean isInserted = mydb.insertData(user_name, user_gender, user_weight, user_height, user_age);
            if (isInserted == true)
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "ADDED", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            else
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "NOT ADDED", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
     };

     builder
         .setView(view)
         .setCancelable(false)
         .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, listener)
         .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.cancel, listener);
     return builder.create();
}
```

You may want to assign on click listeners for radio buttons dynamically as well. `android:onClick` attribute in XML is a way to hell.

Comment: I have tried your solution. The only problem I faced is I dont whether it has  inserted the values in the DB or not. For that we have used toast which doesn't appear when user taps on the DONE button or CANCEL button.

Comment: @Ryder I see you accepted the answer. Did you resolve the issue from comment then? If not I suggest using a debugger and finding out where execution goes sideways.

Answer (score 3):

Use

```
name = (EditText)alert.findViewById(R.id.person_name);
```

instead of

```
name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.person_name);
```

because the views you are accessing are a part of the AlertDialog and not your Activity.
Do the same for all other views of your AlertDialog.

```
AlertDialog.Builder add_people_form = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);

                add_people_form.setView(getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.add_form,null));
 final AlertDialog alert = add_people_form.create();
                        add_people_form.setCancelable(false)
                        .setPositiveButton("DONE", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {


                                name = (EditText) alert.findViewById(R.id.person_name);
                        })
                        .setNegativeButton("CANCLE", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                dialog.cancel();
                            }
                        });

                alert.show();
```

Comment: I have used dialog.findViewbyId because when I was using alert it was showing error but when I used dialog it was fine but now I got the error in findViewbyId() 

what should I do ?

Comment: You have to use alert.findViewById() only. To resolve the error, add this line -   AlertDialog alert = add_people_form.create(); immediately after this line -  AlertDialog.Builder add_people_form = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);

Comment: Also, perhaps you need to setView() like this - add_people_form.setView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.add_form, null));

Comment: Now I am getting two errors
1. I cant see anything in dialogbox when it popups.
2. There is an error in setView() **inflater** inflater.inflate(R.layout....)

Comment: Try add_people_form.setView(getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.add_form,null))

Comment: I cant see my form in dialogbox after taking your suggestion though it doesn't show any error.

Comment: Edited the answer. Try that. I added  only "name = (EditText) alert.findViewById(R.id.person_name);"  to show that you need to do alert.findViewById().You need to initialize your views like that. Also, I added some changes on when and how to inflate your view.

Comment: Now in the dialog box it shows all the form elements except **cancle** & **done** button. They are missing from the dialog popup.

Comment: But there are no such buttons in your xml.How do you think they will get shown ?

Comment: Hey I have been plaaning to use setPositive and setNegative for that but anyway I get everything worked out.

Comment: Cool. Please accept the answer if it helped you for anyone to get help with such issue.

Comment: This answer has worked for me , Thanks  A Lot @Shabad Ansari

Answer (score 0):

Might it be because you're initializing your EditText inside of onOptionsItemSelected than opposed to doing it in the onCreate?

Comment: Actually, it's because it's inside a dialog

Comment: Yes, before I had them inside onCreate but I found somewhere on the slack where the guys had mentioned them inside onOptionItemSelected.