# Custom Dialog error 'android.text.Editable android.widget.EditText.getText()' on a null object reference

Tags: java, android

I have created a custom dialog showing a grid of items. When another option is clicked, it will also open another custom dialog with an editText field. The problem I am facing is getting a null object error for the textfield. I found an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36701022/error-attempt-to-invoke-virtual-method-android-text-editable-android-widget-edi) but when I applied it, the result is still the same.

Basically, the app is crashing when retrieving the textfield value in the custom dialog that opens from another custom dialog. Here is what I have so far:

**onCreate()**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button donate = findViewById(R.id.button);

    donate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            showDonateDialog();
        }
    });
}
```

**showDonateDialog()**

```
//Donate dialog with grid options
private void showDonateDialog() {
    // Prepare grid view
    GridView gridView = new GridView(this);
    String[] donateAmount = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.donationAmount);

    List<String> donateList = new ArrayList<String>();
    Collections.addAll(donateList, donateAmount);

    gridView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, donateList));
    gridView.setNumColumns(3);
    gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Thank you for your donation!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

    // Set grid view to alertDialog
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setView(gridView);
    builder.setTitle("Donate");
    builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.cancel();
        }
    });
    builder.setNeutralButton("Other amount", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            showCustomDonate();
        }
    });
    builder.setCancelable(false);
    builder.show();
}
```

**showCustomDonate()**

```
//Donate dialog for custom amount
private void showCustomDonate() {
    AlertDialog.Builder builderCustom = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    Context context = builderCustom.getContext();
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_donate_amount, null, false);

    final EditText donateAmount = findViewById(R.id.editAmount);
    final DialogInterface.OnClickListener listener = new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            if (which == DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE) {
                dialog.cancel();
            } else {
            String amount = donateAmount.getText().toString(); //Error null object reference here
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Thank you for donating " + amount, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    };

    builderCustom.setView(view)
                .setTitle("Custom Donation")
                .setCancelable(false)
                .setPositiveButton("OK", listener)
                .setNegativeButton("CANCEL", listener)
                .show();

}
```

**Log**

```
    E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.customdialog, PID: 12011
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.text.Editable android.widget.EditText.getText()' on a null object reference
    at com.example.customdialog.MainActivity$5.onClick(MainActivity.java:94)
    at com.android.internal.app.AlertController$ButtonHandler.handleMessage(AlertController.java:166)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i hope it is work for you

**showCustomDonate()**

```
//Donate dialog for custom amount
private void showCustomDonate() {
    AlertDialog.Builder builderCustom = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    Context context = builderCustom.getContext();
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_donate_amount, null, false);

    final EditText donateAmount = findViewById(R.id.editAmount);
    final DialogInterface.OnClickListener listener = new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            if (which == DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE) {
                dialog.cancel();
            } else {
            String amount = donateAmount.getText().toString(); //Error null object reference here
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Thank you for donating " + amount, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    };

    builderCustom.setView(view)
                .setTitle("Custom Donation")
                .setCancelable(false)
                .setPositiveButton("OK", listener)
                .setNegativeButton("CANCEL", listener)
                .show();

}
```

Change on this line

```
final EditText donateAmount = view.findViewById(R.id.editAmount);
```

Comment: Oh my how careless of me. Thank you very much for pointing that out! It works good now.